# How to keep the tab active? ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, navbar, razor-pages

**Hi there,**

I have a problem with my tabs in navbar.

The result I wish:

1. See the "Home" tab class `active` by default
2. Clicking on another tab must to remove `active` class from the `<a>` that is already active (at the starting point it is "Home" tab)
3. Add the same class `active` to the tab I click on (which also mean that app redirects me)
4. Keep the clicked tab `active`

What I've got so far:

1. I see the "Home" tab set `active` by default
2. Clicking on any tab removes class `active` as I mentioned above and adds the same class to the clicked tab
3. Redirection happens and "Home" tab returns its default state (becomes `active` again)

**I share my code below:**

### HTML

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse" id="navigation">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home" asp-area="" asp-page="/home/Index">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="declarations" asp-area="" asp-page="/declarations/Index">Declarations</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="topics" asp-area="" asp-page="/topics/Index">List of Topics</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="contacts" asp-area="" asp-page="/contacts/Index">Contacts</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="faq" asp-area="" asp-page="/faq/Index">FAQ</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

---

### jQuery

```
  $("#navigation .navbar-nav a").click(function() {
    $("#navigation .navbar-nav").find("a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    localStorage.className = "active";
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    stayActive();
});

function stayActive() {
    $(this).children().addClass(localStorage.className);
}
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Razor page, everytime user clicks on a tab, the page will be rendered again on server and then sent back. Therefore I suggest that we set the `active` class on serverside based on the current route.

1. Add a new `HtmlHelper` class

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string ActiveClass(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string route)
    {
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;

        var pageRoute = routeData.Values["page"].ToString();

        return route == pageRoute ? "active" : "";
    }
}
```

2. Go to your `_ViewImports.cshtml` and add this import.
   Without this, it will not recognize the helper we're about to add in step 3.

```
@using <Namespace of the class you wrote in step 1, if not already here>
```

3. Then your cshtml will be

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse" id="navigation">
    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link @Html.ActiveClass("/home/Index")" id="home" asp-area="" asp-page="/home/Index">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link @Html.ActiveClass("/declarations/Index")" id="declarations" asp-area="" asp-page="/declarations/Index">Declarations</a>
        </li>

        ...Same for 3 other tabs, make sure that the route you pass in ActiveClass method
        ...must be the same as the route in asp-page
        ...If you're afraid of duplication, make some static class to store these routes as constants
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I did everything you said but putting @Html into the class, does not affect. Putting it outside the quotes disables asp-route and asp-page tags but at the same time makes these changes I need in navbar. Maybe we should complete the extension to make redirection work?

Comment: @desmondische, This code works,  the only thing you need to do is move the code next to "nav-item" : `<li class="nav-item @Html.ActiveClass("/home/Index")">`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Nam Le answer I suggest complete solution.

I've found the way how can we use the exception properly.

First of all, as we set `active` class on serverside based on the current route, we have to add `asp-route-routeId="{routeId:int}"` in the cshtml we work with.

Secondly, use this jQuery code:

### jQuery

```
   $("#navigation .navbar-nav a").click(function() {
    $("#navigation .navbar-nav").find("a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    localStorage.className = "active";
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    stayActive();
});

function stayActive() {
    $(this).addClass(localStorage.className);
}
```

And the last step is to setup `"launchUrl": "route/routeId"` in the launchSetting.json file to run the application with certain route. This action make our HtmlHelper extension react and add `active` status to the tab we want.

Hope that here is no any gross mistakes in the solution I suggest :)

**UPD: don't forget to add route in cshtml @page "/route/routeId"**